# Invalid WKT string provided to read() error in converting wkt to geojson using wicket

Tags: javascript, geojson, wkt

I want to convert a wkt string received from a textarea in a function called onpaste. But I always got this error :

```
Invalid WKT string provided to read()
```

and this is my simple code and I know that my wkt is correct because I have tested it in another place :

```
var wkt_geom = document.getElementById("inwkt").value;

wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
wkt.read(wkt_geom);
```

and this is my wkt :

```
LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)
```

Comment: Your code and your WKT are correct, however, when is is executed? The `wkt_geom` might be empty if you execute the JS before the `inwkt` HTML element is on the page

Comment: This code is called when something pasted in textarea

Comment: What does `wkt_geom` actually contain? For the error you've mentioned to have been effected, it can't contain the (valid) WKT you've included in your question. Including the code that shows how things are wired up to be "called when something pasted in textarea" would help, too.

Answer (score 1):

> In my case, wkt_geom variable has double quotes along with values. Replace those quotes and try it.

```
console.log('wkt_geom value is ',wkt_geom);
wkt_geom =wkt_geom.replace(/\"/g, "")
```